# OpenLayers see whole map when full screen

Tags: openlayers

I'm working from this example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/fullScreen.html. The version is the latest, 2.13.1. It's showing the full screen capability of OpenLayers, except that it's not possible zoom out to see the *whole* world. It might depend on your screen resolution, but at 1280px, Australia is completely off the screen. I've tried everything including setting `wrapDateLine` on an OSM layer to `false`, with no effect. The correct (sane) behaviour, would be allow zooming out further, even if the world is slightly repeated. This *was* the behaviour until version 2.12. I want to use the latest version, but am stuck with 2.11. I've done this easily in the past with 2.11.

Others libraries such as Leaflet.js and the Google Maps API allow zooming out (and OpenLayers itself until 2.12). Am I missing something, or is OpenLayers broken? This seems like something that should be remarkably simple to achieve...

Comment: You have a point. That looks very broken. However, the 2.11 version, http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/fullScreen.html, looks even worse to me. I see a very zoomed in image located at 0,0, ie, the West Coast of Africa, whereas on the new version I see most of the world, minus Australia, as you point out. I would have thought this should be easy enough to do programatically, though, by setting an appropriate zoom or extents on load. Have you tried that? I am using Chrome on Ubuntu, for what it is worth.

Comment: Yes, I have set extents to the extents of the entire planet, and also set the zoom to 0 and 1. Nothing seems to have any effect. OpenLayers 3 is in the works, and I do like OpenLayers, so I'll probably contribute to the OL3 project make sure the same problem doesn't happen again. I have also tried it on 3 machines, 2 operating systems, and many different browsers.

Comment: Good attitude. OL3 looks great, though bit of a learning curve/change, not that that is a bad thing.